# Bind content of contrentcontrol to selectedvalue of combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, selectedvalue, contentcontrol

I would like to bind content of contrentcontrol to selectedvalue of combobox and set visibility according to trigger. But it is not work. What is the problem ?

```
<DockPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combobo" Padding="4" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBoxItem>0</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentcontrol" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding ElementName=combobo, Path=SelectedIndex}" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Visibility="Visible">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel x:Name="WarningGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <TextBlock Text="Warning" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ContentControl.Content" Value="0">
                        <Setter TargetName="WarningGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
</DockPanel>
```

I also tried it with SelectedIndex but also trigger is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Trigger to DataTrigger

```
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}" Value="0">
         <Setter TargetName="WarningGrid" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
     </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thx for answer, your answer is work only if you bind the selectedindex to content of contentcontrol. Now I'm looking for answer of this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: but you have binded the selectedindex to the content...what problem are you getting